# Export all open order record from IB trader station to csv file

Tags: python, ib-api

I am working on the python program for Ibapi which I can automatedly place order.
Moreover, I would like to export the current open orders from the trader station by the program.

`self.reqAllOpenOrders()`
(Ref: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/open_orders.html)

I am using this command to get all the open orders. It gives all the record in the terminal, and the type of the records are none type. So, I wonder how could I export that record to a csv file.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *

import threading
import time


class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print('openOrder id:', orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, '@', contract.exchange,
              ':', order.action, order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

        self.reqAllOpenOrders()

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

# Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(3)
app.disconnect()
```

Comment: Are you saying this code works?  Because I don't see anything that would call your `openOrder` function at all.  Are you supposed to call `reqAllOpenOrders` in your `__init__`, and it will then call your `openOrder` repeatedly?

Comment: Yes. This code work well in fact.

`openOrder id: 175 TLSA STK @ SMART : SELL LMT 10.0 Submitted
openOrder id: 168 TLSA STK @ SMART : SELL LMT 10.0 Submitted
openOrder id: 167 TLSA STK @ SMART : SELL LMT 10.0 Submitted
openOrder id: 178 MSFT STK @ SMART : SELL LMT 10.0 Submitted`

Here are some output. It seems that it has called the function even I do not include the `self.reqAllOpenOrders`.

Comment: In that case, all you need to do is open the CSV file in `__init__` and write the data in `openOrder` instead of printing it.

Comment: use `self.` to create variable which you can access in all functions in class. ie. `self.file = open(...)` and in other function `self.file.write(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.file = open('file.csv', 'w')

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        mywriter = csv.writer(
            self.file, lineterminator='\n')
        mywriter.writerows([df])
```

Comment: I was looking for the same solution but i am getting error at 'df' .. could you please help - what is df here?